# xfce4 can't create keyboard shortcut with PrintScreen+letter

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, xfce

I used the XFCE GUI tool and every time I input printscreen + u as my shourtcut, xfce ignores the printscreen button in the shortcut.

I also tried to edit the XML conf file with `name="&alt;Print&gt;u"` but it ignores the `u`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only define shortcuts on keychords consisting of one “normal” key and a set of modifiers. The classical modifiers are `Shift`, `Ctrl`, `Meta`, `Alt`, `Hyper` and `Super`. The first four are already taken on a PC keyboard — for historical reasons, `Meta` is more or less an alias of `Alt`. By default the “Windows” key is `Super`, which leaves `Hyper` free. So assign `Hyper` to <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>. Additionally you need to assign it a modifier name; by default `Mod3` is free (the possibilities are `Mod1` through `Mod5`).

The simplest way to do this is through [xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap). Create a file called `~/.Xmodmap` (i..e `.Xmodmap` in your home directory) containing

```
keysym Print = Hyper_L
clear Mod3
add Mod3 = Hyper_L
```

Some distributions load this file automatically during login. If yours doesn't, add the command `xmodmap <~/.Xmodmap` to your [startup applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xfce#Startup_applications).